# How to display only one item at a time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a sidebar menu for Archiving news items. My list shows the years of the news items: 2019, 2018, 2017. When clicked these then display a drop-down container showing the months - September 2019, August 2019, etc.

I'm using a bit of JavaScript to display the drop-down container. The problem I have is that when you click on 2019 and then 2018 both years are showing their relevant months. How do I only show the information for one year at a time? i.e. when clicking on 2019 it displays the months for that year, then when I click on 2018 the content for 2019 hides and only the content for 2018 then shows.

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn-2");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.dropdown-container-2 {
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown-btn-2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="py-1">
  <div class="dropdown-btn-2">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right fa-fw colour-2"></i> 2019
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-container-2 ml-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="december-2019.html">December 2019</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">November 2019</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">October 2019</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">September 2019</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="py-1">
  <div class="dropdown-btn-2">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right fa-fw colour-2"></i> 2018
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-container-2 ml-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">December 2018</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">November 2018</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">October 2018</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">September 2018</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about updating ONLY your javascript like this:

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn-2");

var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   var container = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-container-2");
   var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling; 
   
   if(dropdownContent.style.display == "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
      return; 
   } 
    
    
   for (var j = 0; j < container.length; j++) {
     if(container[j].style.display = "block") {
         container[j].style.display = "none";
      }
   }
   
   dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
   
  });
}
```

1. Check all other containers and hide them
2. toggles show/hide if you are clicking on the same element

codePen available Here: https://codepen.io/ermiarch/pen/XWrQodo

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I forgot to mention the Font Awesome icons that I have before each heading (Year). These unfortunately don't work properly. They work fine if you open and close one year but if I leave one year open (2019) and then click on another year (2018) the Font Awesome icon on 2019 stays downwards pointing. This should point back to it's original position (side-wards) when not active.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you toggle a dropdown, remove the `active` class from all the other ones.
Also it's better to add the `active` class to the dropdown container and then hide the content when that class is missing using css.
Finally, I think it's more neat to manage each group separately (loop the dropdown containers and then add the event listener to the button that is inside them).

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".py-1").forEach(function(dropdown, index, list) {
  dropdown.querySelector(".dropdown-btn-2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    list.forEach(function(item) {
      if (item !== dropdown) item.classList.remove("active");
    });
    dropdown.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-btn-2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.py-1>.dropdown-container-2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: none;
}

.py-1.active>.dropdown-container-2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="py-1">
  <div class="dropdown-btn-2">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right fa-fw colour-2"></i> 2019
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-container-2 ml-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="december-2019.html">December 2019</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">November 2019</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">October 2019</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">September 2019</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="py-1">
  <div class="dropdown-btn-2">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right fa-fw colour-2"></i> 2018
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-container-2 ml-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">December 2018</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">November 2018</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">October 2018</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">September 2018</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that if cannot have smooth transitions when using `display: none` and `display: block` to hide and show the element (`opacity:0` and `opacity:1` works)

Comment: I agree that this is a cleaner solution if you want to use CSS instead of javascript to hide the element

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I forgot to mention the Font Awesome icons that I have before each heading (Year). These unfortunately don't work properly. They work fine if you open and close one year but if I leave one year open (2019) and then click on another year (2018) the Font Awesome icon on 2019 stays downwards pointing. This should point back to it's original position (side-wards) when not active.

Answer (score 2):

When the click event is fired, you should look for all the other active dropdowns and remove the class. It will become something like this:

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn-2");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  
    // Start changes
    var activeDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-btn-2.active");
    for (btn of activeDropdowns) {
      if (btn != this) {
        btn.classList.remove("active");
        var cont = btn.nextElementSibling;
        cont.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    // End changes
    
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.dropdown-container-2 {
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown-btn-2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="py-1">
  <div class="dropdown-btn-2">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right fa-fw colour-2"></i> 2019
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-container-2 ml-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="december-2019.html">December 2019</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">November 2019</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">October 2019</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">September 2019</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="py-1">
  <div class="dropdown-btn-2">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right fa-fw colour-2"></i> 2018
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-container-2 ml-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">December 2018</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">November 2018</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">October 2018</a></li>
      <li class="pt-1"><a href="#">September 2018</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since only one element will be shown at a time, you can also use "querySelector" instead of "querySelectorAll" and avoid the loop, but this is probably safer.

Comment: This no longer toggles the element (you are always removing the active class, so when you toggle it always adds the class)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Edited the answer accordingly, but I still think that the other answers are better layed out (codewise)